# How to install "mat73" package in a conda environment using pip?

Tags: python, matlab, anaconda, conda

I want to open .mat files in python for data analysis. The "mat73" package from https://pypi.org/project/mat73/
allows to do that. But I want to install it into a conda environment and not into the base environment. Since conda (anaconda-navigator) doesn't have this package in its libraries, it can be only installed using pip. I tried installing pip into my conda environment but it always gets installed in the base environment and hence the "mat73" package also gets installed in the base environment. Can someone please help in providing the commands to directly install this package into my conda environment?

Comment: I think you can copy the package into your conda environment? Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility. But there are so many sub-directories in each conda environment that it's confusing for a beginner to figure out where the interpreter looks for the package. Maybe it's easier for an advanced user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to activate your target environment via

```
conda activate myenv
```

Second you install pip into that environment

```
conda install pip
```

finally you could pip-install your package into that environment via

```
pip install mat73
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had always activated my conda environment before performing the pip-install. The thing is pip wasn't installed in my conda environment. Upon installing pip from my conda environment (using: [code] (sudo apt-get install python-pip)), it always installs it into the base environment and hence any packages installed from my conda environment using pip also installs it into the base environment. Secondly, I also tried your suggestion of using : [code] (conda install mat73 -c conda-forge). It gave the error that this package is not available from current channels.

Comment: Then after `conda activate myenv` let `conda install pip` into myenv first.

Comment: It worked this time. Turns out using `conda install pip` is preferable compared to `conda install python-pip`.